# Word VSTO Add-In: Get Working Area Coordinates / Rectangle on Screen

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-interop, office-addins, word-interop

Using the VSTO Word Interop libraries, how can you get the screen coordinates / rectangle of the main "Working Area"?  That is `Left`, `Top`, `Width` and `Height`.

This image quite nicely shows the area I am looking for highlighted as "DISPLAY" - that is the panel/scroll-viewer containing the document.

[image: Working Area Visualisation]

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225518/2708357) which shows a nice approach pertaining to `Range`s and the `Window` itself, but having dug into `Window` / `ActiveWindow`, `View` and `ActivePane`, I was not able to find any properties that get me closer to the "Working Area" I am looking for.

A solution / approach in either C# or VBA would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cindy's kind pointer to the Windows API got me on the right track.

Using the `System.Windows.Automation` namespace and the excellent `inspect.exe` tool, I was able to isolate the `ControlType` containing the document/working area.

In practice, the `Rect` can be obtained as follows:

```
        var window = AutomationElement.FromHandle(new IntPtr(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Hwnd));
        var panel = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Document));
        var docRect = (Rect) panel.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.BoundingRectangleProperty, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

The Word object library provides only information for the height and width:

```
Window.UsableHeight
Window.UsableWidth
```

It provides nothing for the screen co-ordinates of the "editing" section of the Word application, only for the entire application window. For that, I think it will be necessary to work with the Windows API.

Answer (score 0):

If you do now want to use automation `System.Windows.Automation` because for me it is heavy you can use user32 approach.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
    public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
    public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
    public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
}
    
var wwFWindowHandle = FindWindowEx(parentWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "_WwF", null);
if (wwFWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    var wwBWindowHandle = FindWindowEx(wwFWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "_WwB", null);
    if (wwBWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        var wwGWindowHandle = FindWindowEx(wwBWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "_WwG", null);
        if (wwGWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            GetWindowRect(wwGWindowHandle, out var newRect)
        }
    }
}
```

Using this code you will get pages area. Using Spy++ you can find other elements from word office.